# dotnet MAUI Android app does not authenticate, when deployed from play store (using IPublicClientApplication)

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, maui, maui-blazor

I have followed the online instructions to authenticate my dotnet MAUI app against Azure B2C.  This works in iOS, this also works on the Android virtual devices (simulators).  It event works, when debugging it to the physical device.

But when I publish & sign the app (in Release mode, obviously), and deploy the release through an internal test, the authentication does not happen, and I don't get any exception or continuation of the flow.

This is the relevant code, that makes the authentication window popup, using the default browser of my android phone (Google Chrome in my case). But when I enter the (correct) credentials, nothing happens anymore, and the user get redirected back to the app, where the page still shows the user as Unauthenticated. (in the Blazor WebView)

```cs
try
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    var tokens = new List<AuthToken> { };
    var loggedOnAccount = await GetUserAsync();
    if (loggedOnAccount != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Removing code, as this is not reached
            appTracer.Trace($"Logged on Account found: {loggedOnAccount.Username}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            appTracer.Trace($"Error : {e.Message}");
            loggedOnAccount = null;
        }
    }

    if (loggedOnAccount == null)
    {
        appTracer.Trace($"No account found , asking sign on");
        var authSettings = await GetAuthSettingsAsync();
#if ANDROID
        appTracer.Trace($"Android, so WithParent should be called");
#endif

        try
        {
            authResult = await authSettings.Client
                .AcquireTokenInteractive(authSettings.Settings.Scopes)
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
#if ANDROID
            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity)
#endif
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // This line is never reached
            appTracer.Trace(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        // This line is never reached
        appTracer.Trace(
            $"Auth result: {(authResult?.AccessToken)?[5..] ?? "NULL"}");
        tokens.Add(new AuthToken("TokenRetrieval", "Logged on"));
    }


    if (authResult != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authResult.AccessToken))
        {
            tokens.Add(new AuthToken("AccessToken", authResult.AccessToken));
        }

        claimsPrincipal = authResult.ClaimsPrincipal;
        appTracer.Trace($"Persisting tokens");

        await tokenStorage.PersistTokensAsync(tokens);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }

    return authResult;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    appTracer.Trace($"An error occurred during login: {e.Message}");
    throw;
}
```

When I look at the generated output (from the `appTracer.Trace` events), this is what happens:

```
21:38:54.314 - Getting user
21:38:54.446 - Current environment: prd
21:38:54.561 - Account found: NULL
21:38:54.676 - Getting authentication state
21:38:56.383 - Getting user
21:38:56.384 - Current environment: prd
21:38:56.385 - Account found: NULL
21:38:56.385 - No account found , asking sign on
21:38:56.385 - Current environment: prd
**21:38:56.385 - Android, so WithParent should be called**
21:39:21.752 - Getting user
21:39:21.752 - Current environment: prd
21:39:21.753 - Account found: NULL
```

After the bold line (Android, so WithParent...) there should be either an exception (see appTracer), or a line starting with `Auth result`.

I successfully see the log on screen, it's just like the code logic is stopped without exception.

Any idea?